# Understanding memory of Doubly linked list struct

Tags: c, memory, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

This is a homework question. My book does not address how to actually sift through the addresses so I need some help

Given a struct

```
struct lnode {
 struct lnode *prev;
 char *str;
 int strsize;
 struct lnode *next;
};
```

The linked list starts at address 0x0602060, and looking at the memory around that address we see

```
(gdb) x/36x 0x0602010
0x602010:       0x0000000000602060      0x0000000000602040
0x602020:       0x0000000000000016      0x00000000006020b0
0x602030:       0x0000000000000000      0x0000000000000021
0x602040:       0x206d72657464696d      0x756874206e6f2031
0x602050:       0x00000a7961647372      0x0000000000000031
0x602060:       0x0000000000000000      0x0000000000602090
0x602070:       0x000000000000000d      0x0000000000602010
0x602080:       0x0000000000000000      0x0000000000000021
0x602090:       0x6f662074276e6f64      0x0000000a74656772
0x6020a0:       0x0000000000000000      0x0000000000000031
0x6020b0:       0x0000000000602010      0x00000000006020e0
0x6020c0:       0x0000000000000016      0x0000000000000000
0x6020d0:       0x0000000000000000      0x0000000000000021
0x6020e0:       0x2035206573616870      0x6d20657564207369
0x6020f0:       0x00000a7961646e6f      0x0000000000020f11
0x602100:       0x0000000000000000      0x0000000000000000
0x602110:       0x0000000000000000      0x0000000000000000
0x602120:       0x0000000000000000      0x0000000000000000
```

I understand how I would traverse a singly linked list with a single variable in the memory.
I would :

1.Begin at the first address, check where it points to, follow that to the next set of memory

2.The first set of bytes would hold the value in that node, the second set would hold the pointer to the next node

3.Continue

However, this does not work here.

The first node is said to be at 0x602060. Going there and checking the bytes reveals that there are no variable values, followed by a pointer to the next node 0x602090.

```
0x0000000000000000      0x0000000000602090
```

Going to 0x602090 presents bytes in both sections with no apparent return address. Considering the size of the struct I assume that first the char pointer is shown, then the size in the second column as follows

```
 0x6f662074276e6f64 (char*)     0x0000000a74656772 (int with padding)
```

Going on, however, what I'm looking at starts to make less sense
My assumption is that the next two lines

```
  (1) 0x0000000000000000      0x0000000000000031
  (2) 0x0000000000602010      0x00000000006020e0
```

represent (1) some unknown result we don't have to consider and (2) previous pointer followed by next pointer?
But the previous pointer is not the same as the start location. And my assumption that one node is represented by 3 line chunks does not seem to hold starting at address 0x6020e0.

Can someone please give me some hints as to how I am supposed to traverse this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 0x0000000a74656772 is the end of your string in memory. It is not part of a node struct. 0x0000000000000000      0x0000000000000031 are probably the end of the memory allocated for the string of your first node, 31 is the seems to be the allocated size.

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your structure contains 4 64-bit values. The complete structure starting at address 0x602060 is actually spread across two lines of the memory dump:

```
                       prev                     str
0x602060:       0x0000000000000000      0x0000000000602090
0x602070:       0x000000000000000d      0x0000000000602010
                      strsize                   next
```

Notice that `0x0000000000000000` is 64 bits long, or 16 hexadecimal digits.

The pointer 0x0000000000602090 is actually the pointer to the string data (for the node at 0x602060), not the pointer to the next node.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know each value would take up a full 16 hex line because I always have the concept of multiple digits being placed in the same line but I didn't consider that the int HAD TO be alone since every other variable has to take up a whole 16 hex line. Thank you again!